Can I reuse my professional visit Schengen Visa for Tourism Purpose
I have a valid multiple entry type C Schengen Visa with "visite pro" mentioned in its remarks as I applied it for business purposes and have already travelled to France for 23 days and came back to my country leaving the Schengen area. Now I have a vacation planned to France which will be purely for Tourism purpose, Can i re use my Schengen Visa? Or do I have to request to revoke it and apply for a Visa again for Tourism purpose ?
Please do let me know, because i am not able to find a straight answer for this question anywhere.

Yes in my case the business trip is already done , and now again i will entry the schengen area purely for tourism , will "visite pro" mentioned on my visa will cause any problem ?

There are about a dozen duplicate questions on the site.  I've just voted to close all of them but the first one I found, from 2013, as duplicates of that one: Tourism on Schengen business visa?

For the first use of a multiple-entry, 90/180 visa, you have to use it for the premise of your application. For subsequent uses, you can have different purposes.

No, your Schengen visa is a uniform visa, and you are free to use it for any allowed purpose.
The purpose of the visa purpose is to help you get the relevant documents at application-time. And for that, it is in the non-standard remarques/remarks field
